# Neo4j javascript driver configuration errors

Tags: neo4j

I am new using Neo4j in general, but the Neo4j CE 3.1 browser on http connector works very smoothly. Now I need to use JavaScript to develop graph visualisations, and the driver is not working at all. I downloaded the neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1, and 
    npm install 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

```
npm build (fine)
npm test (problems)
```

All I could understand is that the bolt connector need to be configured, so I added to the configuration file to enable the bolt connections. this made the unable to connect message go away. Now I am getting this problem:

```
npm test
> neo4j-driver@1.1.0-dev test C:\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1
> gulp test

[15:00:37] Using gulpfile (node:9436) DeprecationWarning: `DEBUG_FD` is   deprecated. Override `debug.log` if you want to use a different log function (https://git.io/vMUyr)
C:\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1\gulpfile.js
[15:00:37] Starting 'test'...
[15:00:37] Starting 'nodejs'...
[15:00:39] Finished 'nodejs' after 1.86 s
[15:00:39] Starting 'test-nodejs'...
................Structure {
  signature: 127,
  fields: 
   [ { code: 'Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized',
   message: 'The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.' } ] }
FF...........FF.............F(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
(node:9436) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
F(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection  (rejection id: 4): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
F(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection   (rejection id: 7): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 8): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
F(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 10): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 11): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
F(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 13): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
(node:9436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 14): Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
C:\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1\test\v1\examples.test.js:195
expect(out[0].length).toBe(3);
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1\neo4j-javascript-driver-1.1\test\v1\examples.test.js:195:20)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried this from windows 10 command prompt and getting the same response as from inside WebStorm 2016.3.2,

I am also getting the following response when I tried localhost:7687, because I was receiving the error of not able to connect

```
not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade
```

I guess this is because it connects through http, while this port is a bolt connection that runs through the driver only.

I have authentication for the http connection (username and password) for localhost:7474 browser, I appreciate your help on how to configure the authentication for the bolt connection,

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty clear from the error that the user name and password you're using to login to neo4j is wrong:

```
[ { code: 'Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized',
   message: 'The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.' } ]
```